# Is there a way to use the ! operator within the .include? method?

Tags: ruby

I want to write a line of code that checks if an array contains anything other than a 0.  Basically this:

```
if array.include?( ! 0) == false
```

It won't work to write:

```
if not array.include(0)
```

Because I'm not trying to say "If the array doesn't include zero".  I'm trying to say "if the array includes anything that is not zero."

Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

You're checking to see if "not all the values are zero." This directly translates into ruby:

```
!array.all?(&:zero?)
```

Examples:

```
array = []
!array.all?(&:zero?)
# => false

array = [0]
!array.all?(&:zero?)
# => false

array = [0,1]
!array.all?(&:zero?)
# => true
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `#any?` may run faster, since it'll terminate enumeration as soon as finds a value that matches the block, rather than having to check all values in the enumerable.

Comment: @ChrisHeald Not true. Once `all?` finds a non-zero value, it also terminates without having to check all values.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward way to do this is probably `#any?`

```
array.any? {|e| e != 0 }
```

That'll return true if any value in the array is not 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with `include?`. Use [`Enumerable#any?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) instead:

```
if array.any? {|x| x != 0}
```

Isn't it nice how closely that lines up with your original description of "if the array includes anything that is not zero"?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following.

If you want to know if the array contains anything other than the integer zero:

```
def any_non_integer_zero?(a)
  a.any? { |e| !e.is_a?(Integer) || e != 0 }
end

any_non_integer_zero? [0,     0]      #=> false
any_non_integer_zero? [0.0,   0]      #=> true
any_non_integer_zero? ['a',   0.0, 0] #=> true
any_non_integer_zero? [0.1,   0.0, 0] #=> true
any_non_integer_zero? [[0,0], 0.0, 0] #=> true
```

If you want to know if the array contains anything other than the number zero:

```
def any_non_zero?(a)
  a.any? { |e| !e.is_a?(Numeric) || e != 0.0 }
end

any_non_zero? [0,     0]      #=> false
any_non_zero? [0.0,   0]      #=> false
any_non_zero? ['a',   0.0, 0] #=> true
any_non_zero? [0.1,   0.0, 0] #=> true
any_non_zero? [[0,0], 0.0, 0] #=> true
```